# Where is the spam folder?

Tags: solspace-freeform

Using Freeform Lite 1.5.2 for EE. How do I find and review the spam folder? It appears it may be catching too many false positives. What can i do to ratchet back the sensitivity?

Also, why am I the only person who can successfully upload a file through these forms?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Freeform for EE currently does not have a built-in Spam Folder feature yet. It is only available on Freeform for Craft at this time.